# Not able to run postgres, even if `service postgresql status` says it's active

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I have installed postgresql 13

with following conf

pg_hba.conf

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                trust

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            trust

# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::0/00                 trust
```

postgresql.conf

```
#listen_addresses = '*'         # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                                        # (change requires restart)
port = 5432                     # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100                   # (change requires restart)
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3     # (change requires restart)
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql' # comma-separated list of directories
```

when I run  `service postgresql status`, I get
[image]

when I do `sudo su postgres` and `psql` , I get
[image]

Comment: Does `ps -f -u postgres` show that the server is running?

Comment: UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
postgres    1832    1831  0 03:54 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
postgres    2038    1832  0 04:10 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -f -u postgres

Comment: Well, then the server is not running, and you have to start it. Note that your systemd service seems to be configured to start PostgreSQL, but not to make sure it keeps running.

Comment: how can I start it? :/

Comment: @krishnalodha can you try `sudo service postgresql restart`?

Comment: no luck, I tried this `sudo service postgresql restart`. It still shows active when I check status but nothing when I do `psql`

Comment: You can always start the server the PostgreSQL way with `pg_ctl` - see the documentation. Then get someone who knows about systemd to fix the problem.

Comment: Use `systemctl status postgresql@13-main.service` or more the more generic `systemctl status 'postgresql*'`